# How can I assign n number of column names into individual variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a mapping table that contains a list of SourceFields, TargetFields and FileNames.

```
SourceField TargetField Filename

A           1           test.xlsx
B           2           test.xlsx
C           3           test.xlsx
d           1           other.xlsx
e           2           other.xlsx
```

I want to set a SourceField variable, based on the TargetField and FileName`

```
        DECLARE
            @FileName NVARCHAR(MAX)                         
            ,@sql1Target NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@sql2Target NVARCHAR(MAX)
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ,@sql1Source NVARCHAR(MAX)                  
            ,@sql2Source NVARCHAR(MAX)
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ,@sql1Transform NVARCHAR(MAX)               
            ,@sql2Transform NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @FileName = 'other.xlsx'                        
        SET @sql1Target = '1'                   
        SET @sql2Target = '2'

        SET @sql1Transform =                            
            'SELECT
                @SourceField = SourceField
            FROM
                MAPPING_DIM
            WHERE
                TargetField = ''1'' and FileName = ' + ''''+ @FileName +''''
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        SET @sql2Transform =
                'SELECT
                    @SourceField = SourceField
                FROM
                    MAPPING_DIM
                WHERE
                    TargetField = ''2'' and FileName = ' + ''''+ @FileName +''''
```

These statements when executed will return the SourceField based on the other two variables. I can then use these source variables to select from my FileName.

```
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql1Transform , N'@SourceField NVARCHAR (MAX) OUTPUT', @SourceField = @sql1Source OUTPUT
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql2Transform , N'@SourceField NVARCHAR (MAX) OUTPUT', @SourceField = @sql2Source OUTPUT
```

I want to be able to do this for any table containing any number of columns. My problem at the moment is this code will only work as I have set my TargetVariables for when my FileName = 'other.xlsx'. If I was doing this for where the FileName = 'test.xlsx' then I would need to set my variable to include the third field.

Is there any way I can return my SourceFields based on my TargetFields and FileName name for 'n' number of columns in a table?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  I don't think there is a simple method to assign an arbitrary set of values to the results of a query.

I would actually suggest that you just set each value using a separate query:

```
select @a = TargetField
from mapping
where filename = @filename and sourcefield = 'A';

select @b = TargetField
from mapping
where filename = @filename and sourcefield = 'B';

select @c = TargetField
from mapping
where filename = @filename and sourcefield = 'C';
```

If there are no corresponding rows, then the value will not be changed.  However, you could force the value to be `NULL` or some other value using aggregation:

```
select @a = max(TargetField)
from mapping
where filename = @filename and sourcefield = 'A';
```

or:

```
select @a = coalesce(max(TargetField), '<default value>')
from mapping
where filename = @filename and sourcefield = 'A';
```

Note:  This requires knowing all the possible values that could be set.  However, it does not require dynamic SQL.  And, if you are going to use the values, then you need to know the names of the variables in subsequent code anyway.